# How to compare const hex and int?

Tags: c#, comparison, hex

I have some constants, for example:

```
public const int START = 0x00000001;
public const int RING = 0x00000002;
public const int DETECT = 0x00000003;
public const int TYPE = 0x00000004;
public const int PHONE = 0x00000005;
public const int PHONE1 = 0x00000006;
```

And i have value of type **int**, that i get over marshaling some structure.

Can i compare my const and some **int** value (maybe i have wrong definition of my constants)?

I have tried to define my constants as `unchecked((int)0x00000001)`, but it does not work.

Comment: `Konstantin` wants to compare `constants`. :-)

Comment: It must be a constant problem :)

Comment: What actually doesn't work? Have you tried checking (maybe in debugger, or writing to a log file) values that are returned in the structure?

Comment: Guys! Oh my God! I have over 100 constants and i got confused by this! I have compared my value with not actual constants...i have `START` and `START_C`(another const)...sorryyy. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if they have same data type ,they can compare ,no matter whether it is const

This is basic rules.

```
class Program
{

    private const int CONST_INT = 0x10;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CONST_INT==16);
    }
}
```